# Perpendicularity of random variables?

Tags: logistic, classification, random-variable

I am reading Bechavod et al. (2017) [1], and at page 3 there is written:

> In the example, each data point lies in $X = (X_1,X_2) = \{0, 1\}^2$
>   and has two features—$X_1 = A$ is the protected attribute, and $X_2$
>   is a non-protected attribute—and a label in $Y = {0, 1}$. Given
>   $\epsilon \in (0,\frac{1}{4})$, we define a distribution $\mathcal{D}$
>   over labelled examples as follows:
>
> $\mathbb{P}[Y = 1] = 0.5$
>
> $\mathbb{P}[A = y|Y = y] = 1 − \epsilon $
>
> $\mathbb{P}[X2 = y|Y = y] = 1 − 2\epsilon$
>
> Note that $\mathcal{D}_\epsilon$ is defined s.t. $A \,\bot\, X_2|Y$.

What does it mean, mathematically, that $A \,\bot\, X_2|Y$? Aren't those random vectors?

[1] Yahav Bechavod, Katrina Ligett, "Penalizing Unfairness in Binary Classification" ([link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.00044))

Comment: $\bot$ usually means that the random variables in question are _uncorrelated_ (sometimes _independent_, but for _Bernoulli_ random variables, which $X_1=A$ and $X_2$ are, the two properties are the same).  So, I would interpret $A \,\bot\, X_2 \mid Y$ to mean that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are _conditionally independent_ random variables given $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

$\bot$ usually means that the random variables in question are *uncorrelated*; but sometimes it means *independent*. Fortunately, for *Bernoulli* random variables, which $X_1=A$ and $X_2$ are, the two properties are the same).  So, I would interpret $A \,\bot\, X_2 \mid Y$ to mean that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are *conditionally independent* random variables given $Y$.

Let us dissect the given information a little more. We are told that 
\begin{align}
P(X_1 = 1\mid Y = 1) &= 1-\varepsilon\\
P(X_2 = 1\mid Y = 1) &= 1-2\varepsilon
\end{align}
from which we can deduce that
\begin{align}
P(X_1 = 0\mid Y = 1) &= 1 - (1-\varepsilon) = \varepsilon\\
P(X_2 = 0\mid Y = 1) &= 1-(1-2\varepsilon) = 2\varepsilon
\end{align}
but we are *not* told the value of $P(X_1 = 1, X_2 = 1\mid Y = 1)$ explicitly; it is hidden in the $\bot$ statement which says that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are (conditionally) independent given $Y=1$, that is,
$$P(X_1 = 1, X_2 = 1\mid Y = 1) = P(X_1 = 1\mid Y = 1)P(X_2 = 1\mid Y = 1) = (1-\varepsilon)(1-2\varepsilon)$$
 Combining all this, we have that

> Conditioned on $Y=1$, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are conditionally independent Bernoulli random variables with parameters $1-\varepsilon$ and $1-2\varepsilon$ respectively.

A very similar analysis for the case when $Y=0$ gives us that

> Conditioned on $Y=0$, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are conditionally independent Bernoulli random variables with parameters $\varepsilon$ and $2\varepsilon$ respectively.

We readily get that *unconditionally*, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are Bernoulli random variables with parameters
\begin{align}
P(X_1 = 1) &= P(X_1 = 1\mid Y = 1)P(Y=1)+P(X_1 = 1\mid Y = 1)P(Y=0)\\
&= (1-\varepsilon)\frac 12 + (\varepsilon)\frac 12\\
&= \frac 12,\\
P(X_2 = 1) &= P(X_2 = 1\mid Y = 1)P(Y=1)+P(X_2 = 1\mid Y = 1)P(Y=0)\\
&= (1-2\varepsilon)\frac 12 + (2\varepsilon)\frac 12\\
&= \frac 12
\end{align}
*but they are not **unconditionally** independent* since
$$P(X_1 = 1, X_2 = 1) = (1-\varepsilon)(1-2\varepsilon)\frac 12
+ (\varepsilon)(2\varepsilon)\frac 12\neq \frac 14 = P(X_1=1)P(X_2=1).$$